# General Sibling Selector CSS working on test but not on website

Tags: css, css-selectors

My goal is to create some radio buttons with a nice look, and for that I need to stylize the label when the radio is checked. After some research, I found that `~` can work as a conditional with a `:checked` option.

I created a codepen to test my idea first, and it work like a charm, see here: https://codepen.io/SquStouf/pen/GREwwNZ

So the problem is, that it doesn't work on the website in which I try to use it; and I really struggle to understand why.

```css
.radioPro input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.optPro {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  margin: 0 !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.optPro:hover {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

#id1:checked:checked~.id1,
#id2:checked:checked~.id2,
#id3:checked:checked~.id3 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-2 px-0 mx-0 radioPro">
  <input type="radio" id="id1" value="1" name="1-group" />
  <label for="id1" class="id1 optPro"> 1</label>
  <input type="radio" id="id2" value="2" name="2-group" />
  <label for="id2" class="id2 optPro"> 2</label>
  <input type="radio" id="id3" value="3" name="3-group" />
  <label for="id3" class="id3 optPro"> 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: `!important` should be separated by only a space from the value that it references, not a semicolon. But you don't need `!important` on those rules, since the selectors are so specific.

Comment: As far as issues: `#id1:checked:checked~.id2,` should probably be `#id2:checked:checked~.id2,` and all of those could have one less `:checked` in there.

Comment: Thanks ! It was a bad edit from my real code to mask the real id and class name, i edited my original post :)

Comment: Ok ... my bad, all my original id looked like "1idname" or "2idname" ... and CSS don't like a number at start of an id or class ... noob error, nothing to do with the sibling selector.
Problem solved :D

Comment: If you do have an id starting with a digit then the can be selected but with [id="the id"]

Comment: Note that each of your radio buttons has a unique name (in the snippet), so they don't act like radio buttons normally do (allowing only one to be selected at a time). Give them all the same `name` attribute to fix that.